# checkbox, select, radio require bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I would like to know how to include a require for different element like checkbox, select ... not alone but inside a group element

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work as expected

```
    <div class="form-group aria-required="true">
         <div class="radio">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li>
                <input type="radio" name="radio1">
                <input type="radio" name="radio2"> 
                <input type="radio" name="radio3">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `<div class="form-group" aria-required="true">`

Answer (score 0):

The aria-required attribute is used to indicate that user input is required on an element before a form can be submitted. This attribute can be used with any typical HTML form element; it is not limited to elements that have an ARIA role assigned.

HTML5 now has the required attribute, but aria-required is still useful for user agents that do not yet support HTML5.

**Used in ARIA roles**

- Combobox
- Gridcell
- Listbox
- Radiogroup
- Spinbutton
- Textbox
- Tree

**A simple form**

```
<form action="post">
 <label for="firstName">First name:</label>
 <input id="firstName" type="text" aria-required="true" />
 <br/>
 <label for="lastName">Last name:</label>
 <input id="lastName" type="text" aria-required="true" />
 <br/>
 <label for="streetAddress">Street address:</label>
 <input id="streetAddress" type="text" />
 </form>
```

**Working Examples:**
[Link](http://www.oaa-accessibility.org/examplep/tooltip1/)